# Kubernetes: configmaps is forbidden: User "kube" cannot list configmaps in the namespace "default"

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, kops

I followed this tutorial on Medium to deploy a Kubernetes cluster on AWS:
https://medium.com/containermind/how-to-create-a-kubernetes-cluster-on-aws-in-few-minutes-89dda10354f4

However, when I launch the Kubernetes dashboard I see the following errors:

```
configmaps is forbidden: User "kube" cannot list configmaps in the namespace "default"
persistentvolumeclaims is forbidden: User "kube" cannot list persistentvolumeclaims in the namespace "default"
secrets is forbidden: User "kube" cannot list secrets in the namespace "default"
services is forbidden: User "kube" cannot list services in the namespace "default"
ingresses.extensions is forbidden: User "kube" cannot list ingresses.extensions in the namespace "default"
```

Why is this happening?

[image]

Answer (score 8):

The problem is that step 13 of the tutorial reads:

> kops get secrets kube --type secret -oplaintext

It should instead be:

> kops get secrets admin -oplaintext

Answer (score 4):

The `User` you've logged in as, `kube`, doesn't have permission to list the objects that K8s keeps track of. You can either elevate the permissions of `kube`, or create a `ServiceAccount` with the right permissions to list those objects.

Comment: How do I elevate the permissions of kube? How do I create a new ServiceAccount? I'm using kops